# Linkedin ios sdk returns wrong data

Tags: ios, objective-c, sdk, linkedin-api

I have integrated linkedin ios sdk in my ios app. So when I click on button to authenticate with linkedin a viewcontroller is shown and page to enter username and password is shown. Now when I enter the correct username and password it returns a url with code and state in it. The problem is that the state(which is a random string) which was send with the request is not the same that is received in response url. For example if I send

```
state = @"qwertyu"
```

Then the return value is

```
state = @"qwertyu#!"
```

An extra #! is appended with it.

In the code I am checking if the send and received state are same as it is not same I am returning an error(This is the error which it shows after entering correct username and password). If I remove that if condition then it is working perfectly fine.

```
SYLinkedInApplication *app = [SYLinkedInApplication
                              applicationWithRedirectURL:self.redirectUrl
                              clientId:self.appKey
                              clientSecret:self.appSecret
                              state:@"<RANDOM-STRING>"
                              grantedAccess:@[#something];
```

The condition

```
if ([self.application.state isEqualToString:receivedState]) {
    //if true send success
}
```

So my question is

1) Do we need the if condition for checking the state?

2) If we need the condition then why is the return state string different?

Hope the question is clear.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have the same problem it adds `#!` at the end of the state, so when I verify with my own, they are not equal, and I don't want to bypass this verification.. Anyone has a solution for this? I'm doing this with Ionic, but same issue.

Comment: look this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PXuu3t3pIe4

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem (but with Ionic).

1) Yes you should check for the state, to prevent [CSRF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery).

2) That's the problem I solved by changing the URL when requesting authorization and access token:

From https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/authorization to https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization

And https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/accessToken to https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken

That solved my problem. I hope it solves yours too, or someone else's.